max-width: min(60px, 100%) has strange behavior when combined with min-width:fit-content in parent div
I capped the width of the inner div using max-width: min(60px,100%); but the outer div's width is set as if the child had no max width
<style>
   .min-w-fit {
   min-width: fit-content;
   }
   .constrain-width {
   max-width: min(60px,100%);
   } 
   .overflow-y-auto {
   overflow-y: auto;
   } 
</style>
<div
   class="min-w-fit"
   >
   <div
      class="constrain-width overflow-y-auto "
      >
 asdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfasdasdfa
   </div>
</div>

Reproduction - note the bottom scrollbar

This could make sense since min-width: fit-content should fit the (possible) content, but what is perplexing is that replacing the 100% to a fixed value like 90px (eg. max-width: min(60px,90px); fixes the problem. (100vw also fixes it)
Is there some undefined behavior happening since 100% refers to the parent width which is dependent on the child width? Or is the parent div width found first based on the child's unconstrained width and then the child's 100% is applied to the parent's width, which essentially has no effect? It's still odd though.

No idea why this is happening, but changing .min-w-fit to max-width: fit-content; makes the outer respect the minimum possible size of the inner. Doesn't seem to be because of stacking context, but I'm struggling to grasp that, so maybe it is. Lol. display: block is likely relevant, as that prefers to fill the container; inline-block does not fix it though, and inline may but seems just wrong.

Relevant A on similar Q; possible duplicate.
